# Why is $dx$ an infinitesimal?

Tags: calculus, differential

In standard calculus, how can dx be an infinitesimal if infinitesimals do not exists in standard calculus

Comment: You could call $dx$ a differential, and then your question disappears $\ddot\smile$.

Comment: The notation $\int f(x)dx$, the $dx$ is not explicitly an infinitesimal, it should be thought of as a reminder as to which variable we are integrating with respect to, not a manipulable object.

Comment: I believe it's just notation. A lot of notation came before the rigor.

Comment: In standard calculus, $dx$ is just a symbol (or two, for that matter). It can be _interpreted_ as denoting an infinitesimal in suitable sense.

Comment: Infinitesimals are not rigorous in standard calculus, but that doesn't mean we ignore their existence. Non-standard is about creating a structure where math can be done to infinitesimals.

Comment: Recommend reading through the question and answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Since there aren't infinitesimals in standard analysis, $dx$ isn't an infinitesimal. Textbooks telling otherwise should be burned, and the ashes dissolved in acid.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: There are infinitesimals in standard analysis -- it's just that the *real number* system doesn't have any nonzero ones. The dual numbers, for example, are a standard construct. (and very useful, being closely related both to the tangent and the cotangent bundle on the real line)

Comment: @Hurkyl A standard construct, I see... non-standard analysis (not Robinson, but internal set theory, say) seems simple in comparison, though not without pitfalls. I hope you agree that both can't be taught to students of calculus, that would be cruel. You can't do that to mathematics.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown then what exactly is a differential? Specifically, can it be rigorously defined in standard calculus. I know that dy = f'(x)dx, but then what is dx?